# A request for explaining a piece of basic python code about dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I want to ask you for help. I have started learning Python, but I am at the very beginning. From the [website](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted) I took the following code:

```
def take_second(elem):
  return elem[1]

random = [(2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (1, 3)]

take_second(random) # (3, 4)

sorted(random, key = take_second) # [(4, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4)]
```

The problem is, that I have no idea how it works, how it is sorted according to the function `take_second()`.
I understand how the function `take_second()` works - it always takes the element on the 1st position (index = 1). So, for the variable `random` which is a list, it is a tuple `(3, 4)`. And here the problem starts. How the variable `random` is sorted next?

I'm sorry probably it is extremely easy, but I have been thinking for a while about it and nothing, seriously.

Is here anyone who can help me? I would be grateful.

Comment: What happens if you call `take_second` on one of the tuples in the list?

Comment: For example, for the tuple `(3,4)` it takes the element on the position 1, so 4 in this case. However, on the `random` list we do not have an element on a position 4, but we have two tuples which contain 4, `(4,1)` and `(3,4)`. Why the first one was taken not the second one in sorting?

Comment: The `key` argument to sorted is used to extract the value that will be used to sort the collection. In your case, `take_second` just returns the second element of each tuple. Because 4 is the largest (second) value in your collections, `(3, 4)` is the latest item upon sorting.

Comment: However, how the python does it?
When we obtain `(3,4)` we have 4 and this element will be at the end of sorting - we know how `random` look like. But, what python does next? How it compares that 4 with other "second" elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you had a regular non nested list

```
listy = [2,4,3,1]
```

then when you run sorted on it, it will sort it by comparing each element

```
listy = [1,2,3,4]
```

but when you have a list like

```
random = [(2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (1, 3)]
```

you may want to specify how it should be sorted. By taking the function take_second as a key in sorted, it allows the computer to know what to sort the list by. In this case, the computer will compare the second value in each element to determine the ordering, and as you can see in the output, the second values from each tuple do go 1,2,3,4.

```
sorted(random, key = take_second) # [(4, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: Okay! So the whole logic behind this sorting is that the elements defined by the function used as a key, i. e. `take_second()` (in this case) are taken to sorting, so in a nutshell - we sort this stuff by second element in each tuple. Thank you so much !!!!!

Comment: However, how the python does it?
When we obtain `(3,4)` we have 4 and this element will be at the end of sorting - we know how `random` look like. But, what python does next? How it compares that 4 with other "second" elements?

Comment: Check this out: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort. Python uses the quicksort algorithm to sort lists.

Comment: Ok, I guess it is implemented inside the Python. Thanks you! :)